# Generic type that only stores type information

Tags: generics, rust

I need a generic type that stores no data:

```
struct Tag<T>;
```

`rustc` rejects it:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
  = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

While `PhantomData` can solve the problem, it introduces a dependency for derive macros: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&edition=2021&gist=f1c188ea3518a1b42b6b18268e0524ce). Implementing traits manually is an option, but I believe `PhantomData` isn't the best tool for this specific task.

Is there a better way to create a `Tag<T>` type that only stores type information and allows access to `T` within `impl Tag<T>`?

Comment: If you want to make `Tag` generic over `T`, then you have to use `PhantomData`. But maybe you could store information about type `T` as an associated type in some trait that `Tag` would implement.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze, since I'm using `Tag<T>` as a parameter for other generics, it needs to be unique for each `T`.

Comment: can you show your whole usecase then? I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Maybe a bigger picture will help with design decision.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze, while providing clear and concise context might require familiarity with ECS and bevy game engine, here's my situation:

    I manage multiple asset sets.
    I want an event called `Loaded<AssetSet>` that doesn't hold any data itself.
    The actual data resides in a "global" resource.
    Event listeners only need the `AssetSet` type to access this data.

I'm new to gamedev, and I do not like ECS architecture with everything being global and accessible anywhere, but it seems that I have to store assets outside of the event and can not use references.

Comment: `PhantomData` is the *only* way to go to have unused generics, because unused generics on their own are forbidden by the compiler, and therefore you couldn't write `PhantomData` yourself, it has to be a compiler builtin. This is unrelated, though, with the problem of deriving traits being overconstrainted: when you derive `Default`, for instance, it will simply generate a `T: Default` bound on the instance implementation no matter whether the bound is actually useful. In this case, `PhantomData<T>: Default` even if `T` does not implement `Default`. This is a known issue.

Comment: While you can't derive the desired `Default` implementation [writing it is easy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d229cc5ba1ca4b41e9bf87027646206)

Comment: You can use the [derivative crate](https://crates.io/crates/derivative) to get rid of the unwanted dependency on generics: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=95ba743b45cca7400e2cd184347b310f